# What are exactly QSAR models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, data-mining, qsar

I'm reading on the internet about QSAR models and I don't really understand what they are. I see some webs in which some data mining techniques like random forest, CART, etc., are mentioned. What are QSAR models? Is it a specific technique to create a dataset and has nothing to do with classification/regression models, o is a type of models that are created from the data? In addition to your answer, could you post a website or article where this is clearly explained? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_structure%E2%80%93activity_relationship help at all?

Comment: I understand that the only characteristic of "QSAR models" is that the input and output variables of the data are chemical/biological? Should it be called "qsar data" instead of "qsar models"? Any known classification/regression model could be applied to this qsar data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the party.

Based on your comments, it sounds to me that you are more stuck on the term model rather than the QSAR.

A model is not specified by the algorithm that is used to build the model rather a scientific model aims to abstract/explain some natural process or system.

> Scientific modelling is a scientific activity, the aim of which is to
> make a particular part or feature of the world easier to understand,
> define, quantify, visualize, or simulate by referencing it to existing
> and usually commonly accepted knowledge.

Source: Wikipedia

A QSAR model aims to elucidate the relationship between the structure of the molecule and the activity of a given protein. But the algorithm used to build that QSAR model can be anything.